# How to subtract DateTime values and get the Time

Tags: .net, asp.net, c#-4.0

What I basically mean and the exact scenario is.

You have 2 TimeEdit controls in an ASP.NET page. Those take DateTime values.
Now the first represents the time you start working and the second when you finished working.
Can take the working hours with an efficient way?

e.g. 10/6/2011 09:00 - 10/6/2011 17:00 --> 08:00 working hours...

Comment: Is the *working hours* part significant? I.e. 9am one day to 9am next day would that be 24 hours ?

Comment: Zruty's answer is best then :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subtracting two `DateTime`s gives you a `TimeSpan` object:

```
TimeSpan span = timeEnd - timeStart;
Console.WriteLine("Total work hours: {0}", span.TotalHours);
```

Comment: This should work, I guess my problem now is even I changed the pc clock to 24 hour I should play with the Date format of the timeedit controls cause I get 12 hour values....Thanx

Answer (score 1):

Simply subtract them:

```
var workingTime = dateTimeEnd - dateTimeStart;
```