# How do I subtract one DateTime from another?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I have an instance of DateTime that I get from my database, I want to subtract it from `DateTime.Now` and find out if 4 hours were passed. How do I do that?

Also when should i use `DateTime.UTCNow` or `DateTimeOffset`

Comment: Duplicates all over Stackoverflow... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624687/c-how-do-i-subtract-two-dates

Comment: -1 because you didn't do ANY research or even thinking on your own.

Comment: I searched google. And i afraid of making a mistake..it is part of a big code that i have

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the subtraction operator to get a `TimeSpan`:

```
private static readonly TimeSpan MinimumTime = TimeSpan.FromHours(4);

...

if ((dateFromDatabase - DateTime.Now) > MinimumTime)
{
    ...
}
```

As for whether you need `UTCNow` or `Now`... it will depend on what happens to time zones when you fetch the data from the database. `DateTime` is not terribly clear on this front :(

If you can fetch the value as a `DateTimeOffset` to start with, then you can use `DateTimeOffset.Now` instead and it should be simpler to work out any time zone issues.

Comment: I have a site that is in my local language (not english), so i dont think i will have the issue of TimeZones

Comment: @Matrix001: Languages and time zones are very different things. It will depend on how the database stores (and returns) `DateTime` values etc. Don't assume it'll be okay just because everything is in one time zone...

Comment: So if it stores 14:00, i might end up with 16:00? Does it depend on where the database is located? I read that DateTime is sensitive to regional changes while DateTimeOffset isnt.. so how can i get in trouble for using DateTime?

Comment: @Matrix001: It will depend on your database, and potentially the schema. You can get in trouble using DateTime because a DateTime *can* be UTC or it *can* be "local". It's basically unclear. A DateTimeOffset *always* represents an instant in time.

Answer (score 4):

[DateTime.Subtract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ysw4sby.aspx)

First Google hit..

Comment: Also a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6304514/how-to-subtract-datetime-values-and-get-the-time

Comment: Except that that's not actually the idiomatic way to do it, as you probably want to use the subtraction *operator*.

Comment: Sure but my point was more that he could typed 2 words into the address bar of his browser to get his answer. ;) Also the operator-style is described on that page. :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
bool fourHoursPassed = date.AddHours(4) < DateTime.Now;
```

or this to actually perform a subtraction:

```
bool fourHoursPassed = (DateTime.Now - date).TotalHours > 4;
```

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime.Subtract`

or

`DateTime myDateTime = someValue;
TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now -myDateTime;
if(ts.Hours>=4)
{
  doSomething();
}`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

DateTime dt = new DateTime(2011, 07, 10);
DateTime dob = new DateTime(1987, 07, 10);

You can simply subtract as:
TimeSpan age = dt - dob;